# How do I hang a wall accessory fitted with 'Wall Grabbers' by Pinnacle?

Tags: mounting, shelving

How is this shelf meant to be hung? Should I just use two screws into the drywall? It won't be supporting anything heavy, but screws don't seem like they would make the shelf mount flush to the wall.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The manufacturer has a video on their website that demonstrates how to hang their products that incorporate their Wall Grabber technology.

pinnacleframe.com -> Products ->  Gallery Solutions -> Click to watch video

or

http://blog.pinnacleframe.com/Pinnacle_Video/GallerySolutions_Pinnacle.mov